# How make signature in Amazon S3 in C

Tags: c, amazon-s3, sha1, hmacsha1

I'm writing in C, I'm using libcurl+openSSL to send POST request. In case of Amazon S3, I have to make [signature in my request](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/dev/index.html?UsingAuthAccess.html), that is formed as RFC 2104 HMAC-SHA1 from AWS Secret Access Key. Advise, please, where can I get the implementation of that algorithm, that will suit Amazon? Is [openSSL function SHA1](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/sha.html) the one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HMAC is a way to combine a message and a key securely using a hash function (in this case SHA1). Fortunately, OpenSSL includes an implementation of both, so you shouldn't need to touch the SHA1 function directly. See the [documentation for HMAC](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/hmac.html) in OpenSSL.